# Need a PHP interpreter

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress site that I believe has some serious security issues, and I found a large 'cache' directory on the site with gibberish architecture. Below I am pasting the contents of one .php file, and I am hoping someone can tell me what this does. I see that it is interacting with the wordpress database, and the IP address being checked appears to belong to Microsoft, but beyond that I'm clueless. For what it's worth, the path/to/file is something like: /cache/db/000000/bb7/f95/dfa/bb7f95dfab264023ffcd917f9187bed2.php

```
�S<?php exit; ?>a:6:{s:10:"last_error";s:0:"";s:10:"last_query";s:57:"SELECT id FROM wp_IPBLC_blacklist WHERE IP='157.55.35.33'";s:11:"last_result";a:0:{}s:8:"col_info";a:1:{i:0;O:8:"stdClass":13:{s:4:"name";s:2:"id";s:5:"table";s:18:"wp_IPBLC_blacklist";s:3:"def";s:0:"";s:10:"max_length";i:0;s:8:"not_null";i:1;s:11:"primary_key";i:1;s:12:"multiple_key";i:0;s:10:"unique_key";i:0;s:7:"numeric";i:1;s:4:"blob";i:0;s:4:"type";s:3:"int";s:8:"unsigned";i:1;s:8:"zerofill";i:0;}}s:8:"num_rows";i:0;s:10:"return_val";i:0;}
```

Comment: It's actually not executing at all - see `exit;` - but it's serialized data. If you're curious, the unserialized data looks like this: https://eval.in/106037

Comment: I think those could be generated by a PHP module like APC that enhances performance

Comment: Is there more to the file?

Comment: It's a cache file... http://codepad.org/aaYwinAH - Looks to store a table description and result set

Comment: Every file appears to begin with the 'exit;' line. The site does run W3 Total Cache. You think that is creating these thousands of files? Seems strange if they don't _do_ anything.

Comment: They don't do anything by themselves, that's why the `exit` commands are there. Wordpress will be opening and using them as cache files, and removing the `exit` commands presumably. They'll be there so you can't execute the file directly through your browser or otherwise.

Comment: Good to know. The file paths/names had me worried, but I guess I need to keep scouring. Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Well, `exit` kills it before it really does anything...

But that string is a serialized array.

you can copy+paste it into `unserialize` to see it more clearly. (and by changing the single quotes to double quotes in that one spot)

here:

http://3v4l.org/VQ6RJ